# Export data from InterBase / Firebird database without credentials

Tags: firebird, interbase

I have an InterBase / Firebird database file of an old project for which I lost the credentials. Some information about the database, dumped with the `gstat` command, is shown below [1]. I'm accessing this file as an embedded database, i.e., without a running instance of Firebird. I'm on MacOS and I've Firebird 2.5 installed, since On-Disk Structure (ODS) 11.2 corresponds to this version.

I'm able to export the database structure using the `isql` command, but I'm unable to access any data using this tool without a valid username and password, resulting in the following error message:

```
Error while preparing SQL statement:
- SQLCODE: -551
- no permission for read/select access to TABLE FILES', -551, 335544352
```

Providing the default SYSDBA/masterkey as the username/password results in the error message:

```
Error while connecting to database:
- SQLCODE: -902
- cannot attach to password database', -902, 335544653
```

Since encryption was introduced in the newer Firebird 3 and the data is stored unencrypted (I can view the data with a hex editor) I'd assume there is a way to access this data without credentials and make an export. How can I do so?

[1]: Output of the `gstat` command

```
Database "./DATABASE.GDB"
Database header page information:
    Flags           0
    Checksum        12345
    Generation      26450714
    Page size       4096
    ODS version     11.2
    Oldest transaction  25058616
    Oldest active       25058617
    Oldest snapshot     25058617
    Next transaction    25058619
    Bumped transaction  1
    Sequence number     0
    Next attachment ID  1401189
    Implementation ID   26
    Shadow count        0
    Page buffers        0
    Next header page    0
    Database dialect    1
    Creation date       Jul 21, 2014 13:42:21
    Attributes      force write

    Variable header data:
    Sweep interval:     20000
    *END*
```

Answer (score 2):

The second error `cannot attach to password database`, that is given when the username and password are provided, is due to the fact that the security database couldn't be opened.

On macOS this file is located under:

`/Library/Frameworks/Firebird.framework/Resources/English.lproj/var/security2.fdb`

and is owned by the `firebird` user by default. This causes problems when the administrative tools (`isql`, `gsec`, `gfix`, etc.) are ran as a different user.

One way to solve this issue is to run those command as the `firebird` user. Another is to change the permissions of the security database:

`chmod o+r /Library/Frameworks/Firebird.framework/Resources/English.lproj/var/security2.fdb`

This solved the issue and data could be accessed using the default sysdba/masterkey credentials. These are **not** stored in the GDB file, but in the mentioned `security2.fdb` file, which explains why the default credentials can be used.

Comment: For ISQL, you could also connect through Firebird server (by connecting to `'localhost:<path-to-db>'`, instead of trying direct file-access using Firebird embedded (which is what happens if you use ISQL without specifying a host name).